# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 drawing line between two location

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

please help me on this, I really stuck on this!
my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

  var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address2': address2}, function(results2, status2) {
    if (status2 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results2[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });

  var myTrip = [address,address2];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path:myTrip,
      strokeColor:"#00F",
      strokeOpacity:0.8,
      strokeWeight:2
  });

flightPath.setMap(map);
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="address 1">
      <input id="address2" type="textbox" value="address 2">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to enter two address in the input, convert it to lat/long separately, put two markers on the map and draw a straight line between them!
my code is not working, it's displaying only the first address and that's all...
thank you in advance!

Comment: check in `console` what error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that you had at least syntax error (`address2`) because you defined:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address2': address2}, function(results2, status2) {
```

instead of:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address2}, function(results2, status2) {
```

However, you also had errors when defining the actual polyline, because geocoding is *asynchronous* you cant call creation of the polyline after geocode lines, instead you need to make separate method or similar callback functionality which is called when geocoding finishes. Otherwise, you are just handling `undefined` values.

Therefore, I decided to add method called `displayMarkers()` which is called from each geocode request which in turn checks whether all addresses is geocoded and acts accordingly.  Here is the code with the changes: (It also works without page refresh, you can try seaching multiple addresses in a row).

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var geocodeMarkers = [];
var flightPath;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {

  // Emptying last addresses because of recent query
  for(var i = 0; i < geocodeMarkers.length; i++) {
     geocodeMarkers[i].setMap(null);
  }  

  // Empty array
  geocodeMarkers.length = 0;

  // Empty flight route
  if(typeof flightPath !== "undefined") {
     flightPath.setMap(null);
     flightPath = undefined;
  }  

  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        // Adding marker to geocodeMarkers
        geocodeMarkers.push(
            new google.maps.Marker({
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            })
        );

        // Attempting to display
        displayMarkers();

        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }

  });

  var address2 = document.getElementById('address2').value;

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address2 }, function(results2, status2) {

    if (status2 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

       // Adding marker to geocodeMarkers
       geocodeMarkers.push(
           new google.maps.Marker({
               position: results2[0].geometry.location
           })
       );

       // Attempting to display
       displayMarkers();

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }

 });


}

function displayMarkers() {

  // If geocoded successfully for both addresses
  if(geocodeMarkers.length === 2) {

    // Bounds for the markers so map can be placed properly
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
       geocodeMarkers[0].getPosition(),
       geocodeMarkers[1].getPosition()
    );

    // Fit map to bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    // Setting markers to map
    geocodeMarkers[0].setMap(map);
    geocodeMarkers[1].setMap(map);    

    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path: [geocodeMarkers[0].getPosition(), geocodeMarkers[1].getPosition()],
       strokeColor:"#00F",
       strokeOpacity:0.8,
       strokeWeight:2,
       map: map
    });

  }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Working jsfiddle example: **[js fiddle demonstration 1](http://jsfiddle.net/4rsME/)**

**Edit:**

After further comments, author of this topic wanted to center map on first geocoded marker. It is accomplished by changing following lines:

```
// Bounds for the markers so map can be placed properly
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
   geocodeMarkers[0].getPosition(),
   geocodeMarkers[1].getPosition()
);

// Fit map to bounds
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

To:

```
// Center map to first geocoded location
map.setCenter(geocodeMarkers[0].getPosition());
```

Working jsfiddle for this: **[js fiddle demonstration 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4rsME/2/)**

Comment: thank you very much Mauno! I really apreciate your help!
it's working very well!
also if you can help me just a liitle bit more it would be very good!
I try to center the map to the first address after I geocoding the location, but with no success :(

this is the cod that I try:

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            ...
thanky you very much in advance!!

Comment: @user3488958 Okey, I created example about it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4rsME/2/ You can see the map centering done at the bottom part of the script, inside displayMarkers method. I didn't put it part of this answer but feel free to accept if it is now done. Cheers. :)

Comment: Mauno, just one more thing. I am ashamed, but plese if you can put in the code, to display the distance(km) between this two location. in the "panel" DIV. thank you in advance and sorry about this!

Comment: Goes beyond the question, but I guess it doesn't make harm to include it into the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/4rsME/3/ (see that I added &libraries=geometry) to the js map api url.. so it should be changed to: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=geometry - For the rest, make new questions or use search if problems occurs :)